# openGL 2D moving and object by 1 unit

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d, glut

I have some questions about how to move an object by pressing a key.  All I want to do is to press the up button in my keyboard and make the object move one unit.

```
void display(){

    //Clear Window
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glPushMatrix();
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2f(-0.1, -0.2);
    glVertex2f(-0.1, 0.2);
    glVertex2f(0.1, 0.2);
    glVertex2f(0.1, -0.2);
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();
}


void keyboardListener(int key)
{  
    if( key == GLUT_KEY_UP) 
    {
        glTranslatef(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glutPostRedisplay(); 
    }
}
```

Whats missing or what concept I am not understanding?

Comment: Do you get the key up event ? What happens ?

Comment: 1st: You need to tell us what is NOT working in your solution. 2nd: Try to rephrase your question into a general question, not a "debug my code".

Comment: the translation is making the object go 1 unit up in the x axis is it not? so all values in "x" that polygon will go up one unit  instead of -0.1 one in the image would be 0.0 and 0.1  would be 0.2. I also find out weird that if I press the right button, the square will stay pointing 90 degrees. Which function will allow me to in this case turn 90 degrees to the right leaving it pointind towards 0 degrees? All this without changing the escene because I think rotatef changes the view, not really the physical position of the object

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>

GLfloat rotation = 90.0;
float posX = 0, posY = 0, posZ = 0;

void reshape(int width, int heigth){
    /* window ro reshape when made it bigger or smaller*/

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    //clip the windows so its shortest side is 2.0
    if (width < heigth) {
        glOrtho(-2.0, 2.0, -2.0 * (GLfloat)heigth / (GLfloat)width, 2.0 * (GLfloat)heigth / (GLfloat)width, 2.0, 2.0);
    }
    else{
        glOrtho(-2.0, 2.0, -2.0 * (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)heigth, 2.0 * (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)heigth,2.0 , 2.0);
    }
    // set viewport to use the entire new window
    glViewport(0, 0, width, heigth);
}

void rect(){
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2f(-0.1, -0.2);
    glVertex2f(-0.1, 0.2);
    glVertex2f(0.1, 0.2);
    glVertex2f(0.1, -0.2);
    glEnd();

}

void display(){
    //Clear Window
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(posX,posY,posZ);
    rect();
    glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();
}


void init(){
    // set clear color to black
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    // set fill color to white
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    //set up standard orthogonal view with clipping
    //box as cube of side 2 centered at origin
    //This is the default view and these statements could be removed
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);

}
float move_unit = 0.1f;
void keyboardown(int key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key){
        case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
            posX+=move_unit;;
            break;

        case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
            posX-=move_unit;;
        break;

        case GLUT_KEY_UP:
            posY+=move_unit;;
            break;

        case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
            posY-=move_unit;;
        break;

        default:
         break;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}


int main(int argc, char** argv){

    //initialize mode and open a windows in upper left corner of screen
    //Windows tittle is name of program

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("Practice 1");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    init();
    glutSpecialFunc(keyboardown);
    glutMainLoop();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to do something like so

```
float posX = 0, posY = 0, posZ = 0;

void display(){
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glTranslate(posX,posY,posZ);
  drawPolygon();
  //...
}


void keyboardListener(int key){
  if(key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT){ posX++; }
  else if(key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT){ posX--; }
  //..similar for up/down
  glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Comment: Thank your for your response, it looks easier to understand, so it is not necessary for me to use the push and pop?

Comment: no not in this case, just make sure drawPolygon() is drawn centered at origin, then go on from there

Comment: In which cases do i use push and pop? Sorry to be annoying. When I try to apply this the image is not redrawn and the object does not move either.

Comment: you might need to add glutPostRedisplay inside your display function, post your code in codepad.org if its small enough so I can take a look

Comment: Thanks for all your help!! Basically I came with the idea of making like a laberinth where an object needs to finish it just simple stuff with some squares as walls. I did a project in c++ last year about a maze and I just thought of the idea of implementing graphics http://codepad.org/ERyTZyYy

Comment: you need to register your keyboard function with glut

Comment: sorry computer died, look up glutSpecialFunc

Answer (score 0):

This code draws a circle and is moved upon left, right, up or down key pressed.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
float posX = 0.01, posY = -0.1, posZ = 0;

void circ() {
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 300; i++) {
        angle = 2 * PI * i / 300;
        x = cos(angle) / 20;
        y = sin(angle) / 20;
        glVertex2d(x, y);
    }
    glEnd();
}


void display() {
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(posX, posY, posZ);
    circ();
    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

**float move_unit = 0.02f;
void keyboardown(int key, int x, int y) {
    switch (key) {
    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
        posX += move_unit;
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
        posX -= move_unit;
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_UP:
        posY += move_unit;
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
        posY -= move_unit;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
glutPostRedisplay();
}**



int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(600, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("Example");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutSpecialFunc(keyboardown);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Co-ordinates of circle are updated upon every time arrow key is pressed.